# Curly brackets after for statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

I'm a newbie.
Wrote a code to print sum of number from 1 to 10.
Here's what happened;

```
for(a = 1; a<=10; a++)
sum += a;
cout<<sum;
```

Executing that gave me the correct answer i.e 55

When I execute the following:

```
for(a = 1; a<=10; a++)
{
sum += a;
cout<<sum;
}
```

It gives me a complete different and wrong answer i.e 13610152128364555

Why does this happen? 
What goes wrong when I put curly brackets after for statement?

I hope this is not a silly question.

Comment: You're printing the number after every iteration... `1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55`, just without spaces. Seriously, a little bit of research / "googling" would have told you the answer.

Comment: As always when such basic things remain unclear to someone I feel urged to suggest [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). My suggestion for beginners: [Accelerated C++](http://www.amazon.com/dp/020170353X/?tag=stackoverfl08-20).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you break apart that big number:

```
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

you can see what's happening - it's actually outputting the accumulated sum after *every* addition, because your `cout` is within the loop. It's just hard to see because you have no separator between all those numbers.

You'll see the difference if you format your code properly:

```
for(a = 1; a<=10; a++)
    sum += a;             // Done for each loop iteration
cout<<sum;                // Done once at the end.

for(a = 1; a<=10; a++)
{
    sum += a;             // Done for each loop iteration
    cout<<sum;            // Done for each loop iteration
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Isn't it supposed to be 

for(a = 1; a<=10; a++) 
{
 sum += a;
}
cout<<sum;

?

That gives me the right answer.

Comment: @judas: Yes, but you don't _need_ the braces if there's only one statement in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

because:

```
for(a = 1; a<=10; a++)
sum += a;
cout<<sum;
```

is like saying:

```
for(a = 1; a<=10; a++) {
    sum += a;
}
cout<<sum;
```

When you do this, it prints the number once rather than upon each iteration.

Comment: @judas,print a newline after sum,you will see the difference

Comment: The bits in the braces will be executed as part of the for-loop, the `cout << sum` after the loop.

Comment: @judas everything inside the curly brackets gets executed inside the loop. Everything outside them doesn't.

Comment: @judas it's the difference from writing `cout<<sum;` at each iteration or after the for loop is complete. since 55 is the output you wanted to see and you did not want `sum` printed upon each iteration, you would want to print it after the loop is complete.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you are executing cout<

In the second you are calling it every execution of the loop.
That makes it print 1, then 3, then 6 ... always appending it, since there is no newline. As you can see you have 55 as last output.

Answer (score 0):

Because the code in curly braces is executed until the condition in for loop becomes false.